# Admob Use Same Interstitial and BannerID for both Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, admob

I have developed an application for both platform IOS and Android. Over AdMob page I have created only one app with two Ad Units, so I have two Ad Unit IDs(Banner and Interstitial),

Can I use these Unit Ids for the applications both IOS and Android?
Or Do I need to create two Applications over Admob corresponding platform, then use Ad Unit Ids created under this section.

I am using Ionic 1 cross platform.

Comment: Do not use same ID across cross platforms. You can use it across same platform. e.g. Create one banner ID for Android, same ID can be used for all other apps on Android . But always keep it separate for tracking purpose.

Comment: If I use same ID, does it cause the income lose for me?

Comment: theoretically no there will not be any loss .. but while creating a new ID . admob asks for platform.. there is reason for that... most of ads shown are relevant to platform. You don't want to see a android app installation ad in iphone? Also for reporting tracking purpose it's good practice to create separate id's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really recommend to separate banner id as different as possible.
use `var isAndroid = ionic.Platform.isAndroid();` to detect OS type and put different banner ids.

Comment: Thanks, If it may cause me losing any income, I will immediately publish a new IOS releas, but now I will wait for a while to release mature application after fixing some sort of problems other than that.

Comment: @AhmetKarakaya i would recommend to merge admob and firebase analytics. Google detects any user via firebase and shows the most wanted ad for him

Comment: Actually, as far as I know ionic 1.0 does not have firebase plugin yet.